# Angular - generate routerLink with secondary route

Tags: angular, routes

With Angular 8, I created a "login callback" page that should redirect (by link, or automatically) to the previous page. But previous page can contains some secondary routes.

So, to avoid "full reload" of the page on navigation, I tried to use [routerLink] in the template to build the "go to previous page" button, and "this.router.navigate(...)" inside the controller if I want to redirect programmatically.

The problem is :
It seems that Angular cannot serialize correctly the secondary route (with parenthesis)

Example :

**Controller:**

```
constructor(private router: Router){}

public redirectRoute: string;

onInit() {
  this.redirectRoute = '/home(modal:modal/secondary);param1=value1';
}
```

**Template:**

```
<a [routerLink]="redirectRoute">Go to previous page</a>
```

The URL built serialize parenthesis, **(** becomes **%28**, and **)** becomes **%29**. So navigation fails, route isn't recognize and it fallback on default route.

In fact, "redirectRoute" is dynamic, so I don't look for an answer like "build redirectRoute in the template directly". Of course it works, but I can't.

I tried many things ; I can parse the URL (with `this.router.parseUrl(rawRedirectUrl);`), it returns a good URLTree (secondary route is well formed), but I don't find how to use an URLTree into [routerLink] tag.

Same thing occured if I want to redirect with `this.router.navigate(this.redirectRoute)`...

How to redirect properly without reloading all the page ?

Thanks !

**[EDIT]**

I opened https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35414

Comment: `this.router.navigate(['../', {id:this.prameterID}],{relativeTo: this.activatedRoute} )` this navigate to previous routed history and then we can also set optional parameter to previous route to get notify we come from `this.parameterID`

Comment: I don't want to redirect to the direct previous page ; it's the functional workflow, but behind the scene there is more redirections with final target as a parameter

Comment: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3368-prevent-routing-to-secondary-view-if-page-refresh-in-angular-5-0-0.htm this reference can help you

Comment: This guy removes a secondary segment ; I want to use it in [routerLink] ;)

Answer (score 0):

Router link also accespt a url tree.

So doing the following:

```
<a [routerLink]="[ '/home', {param: 123 } ]">Home</a>
```

Will generate the link '/home;param=123'.

Example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qcpcoy

The stackblitz example routes between two components. I am constructing my links using the syntax above, and then reading logging the param to the console via the injected `ActivatedRoute`.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.route.snapshot.params['param']);
}
```

Comment: You build the link manually into the template, that's exactly what I'm not looking for, as I said in the question ;) Consider that you don't know the path, nor the params, nor the secondary route, etc. EDIT: routerLink doesn't accept an URLTree object, try `[routerLink]="aRealUrlTree"` with `this.aRealUrlTree = this.router.parse('/home;param=123');`

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed that. Do you have a working example?

Comment: Huh no, that's why I'm asking here :/ You mean a stackblitz of the problem ?

Comment: Ha. Yeah by "working" I meant "live". Then we can at least be working under the same assumptions.

Comment: You can use that : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9qzcmh
Check the href behind the links, one is good, the second is encoded

Comment: Thanks for the example, that's much clearer now. This is an interesting one. I forked your example and tried url parsing using the url serialzer, but the parsing is failing. I've had issues with routing in stackblitz before, so don't know if it's just that, or my approach genuinely doesn't work. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbddfw

Comment: It's also possible to write your own url serializer - that might be one option if all other avenues have been exhausted?

Comment: Your parse works, and the console.log is here ; but you try to use UrlTree object into [routerLink], as I said, this doesn't work :)

Comment: I tried with custom UrlSerializer, it leads to worst situation... For the moment, it works only with [href] attribute so it reloads the page... And navigateByUrl for the controller side. Nothing better, I wait after my Github issue :/

Comment: Shame. Best of luck!